# Can I take a range of cells, remove duplicates and blank cells, then copy into an already existing table in VBA Excel?

Tags: vba, excel

I am very new to VBA so forgive me if I'm doing this completely wrong. Basically, to give an overview of what I'm doing, I have a template that is filled out by a user. There are values spread out over the template that I need to add to a table but I don't want to add blanks or duplicates. I started by condensing them in a continuous range and I was able to figure out how to remove the duplicates, but I can't remove the one blank that is left. Also, I'm not sure the best way to add them to the table on another worksheet. This is what I have so far...

```
Sub UpdateKey()

 Range("P10:P36").Select

 Selection.Copy
 Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

 Selection.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo

End Sub
```

Like I said, this always leaves me a blank right in the middle which I don't know how to get rid of, and I don't know where to go from here to add what's left to my table. Thanks for any help!

Comment: You can order it after `RemoveDuplicate`. Record a macro then Order A->Z to see the code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try to use following code:

```
Sub UpdateKey()
    With Range("P10:P36")
        .Value = .Value
        .RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
        On Error Resume Next
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Delete xlShiftUp
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: + 1 on the use of `.Value = .Value` and `SpecialCells` :)